# Add Freemarker support to customized JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, freemarker, taglib

I have a customized JSP tag library with a Java class (extending TagSupport) that generates the output for my web application. It has some parameters that are formed into HTML code using a `StringBuilder`.

Now the generated HTML is becoming more complex and hard to handle with calls of `StringBuilder.append`, so I'd like to replace the code generation with a `Freemarker template`.

I already found out that I could use a generic Struts `component` tag instead, because the Struts tags already use Freemarker template files, so I could write a tag like:

```
<s:component template="/components/myStruct.ftl">
    <s:param name="myParam" value="%{'myParam'}" />
</s:component>
```

Then writing the specified template file `myStruct.ftl` would probably solve my problem. I actually did not try if Struts really finds and uses that file correctly, but I optimistically expect it to work.

My question is, if it's also possible to retain the current code with the customized tag

```
<my:struct param="myParam" />
```

and only change the Java class linked to that tag.

I've found code that reads a Freemarker template:

```
Configuration config = FreemarkerManager.getInstance().getConfiguration(pageContext.getServletContext());
config.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(pageContext.getServletContext(), "/components");
Template templ = config.getTemplate("myStruct.ftl");
templ.process(params, pageContext.getOut());
```

but it seems very circuitously to me and I wondered what would be the "standard" way to do it. Additionally it seemed that you cannot use tags from the Struts tag library in a template used like this. (I ran into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, caused by `Sitemesh`... I did not analyze it yet.)

My intention was to keep the Java class as some kind of wrapper around the Struts component tag. Maybe somthing like:

```
OgnlValueStack stack = TagUtils.getStack(pageContext);
Component c = new Component(stack);
c.addParameter("param", param);
```

But I don't know how to continue this code stub. It may be crap anyway.

Is there an easy/"standard" way to do this or do I simply have to get rid of the customized tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is also possible (and completely fine) for you to continue to have used your custom JSP tag and simply implement Freemarker (or a different templating language) to render the markup for the tag.

Comment: After implementing it in the way posted hereunder, I first ran into the same `Sitemesh` error (which was only a consecutive error of wrong FTL syntax). So I think it would also have worked. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine sent me this link:

http://cppoon.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/how-to-create-a-struts-2-component-with-freemarker/

This is what I was looking for. The gist is to change the customized tag to not extend `TagSupport`but `AbstractUITag` which makes it a Struts tag instead of a JSP tag, roughly speaking.

This enables the automatic linkage (by name and path conventions) to my Freemarker template. I basically followed the instructions on that page. I only added the methods that are abstract in the super class, so they had to be implemented.

IMO the site lacks of a description of how the UI bean class is linked to the tag class. But as the IDE forces you to implement the `getBean` method inside the tag class, you quickly get to this code (using the classes described on that site):

```
@Override
public Component getBean(OgnlValueStack stack, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    Pagination pagination = new Pagination(stack, request, response);
    pagination.setList(list);
    return pagination;
}
```

This might not be completely correct for the recent Struts, but it worked for the ancient version I've got to use.

Thanks again to the guy who sent me the link :)